# An analogue of Jacobi's formula for the matrix permanent

Tags: matrices, permanent

Is there an analogoue to [Jacobi's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula) for the matrix permanent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See section 4 of [Derivatives of tensor powers and their norms](https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.2414) (2011):

The Jacobi identity for the derivative of a determinant,
$$d \det (A) = \operatorname{tr} (\operatorname{adj}(A) \, dA),$$
has the analogous formula for the permanent in terms of the  *permanental adjugate* of $A$: the $n\times n$ matrix whose $(i, j)$-entry is $\operatorname{per} A(i|j)$, where $A(i|j)$ denotes the $(n − 1) \times(n − 1)$ submatrix obtained from $A$ by deleting its $i$th row and $j$th column.

Answer (score 2):

Of course there is such a formula, but this is quite a tautology:
$$\frac{d}{dt}{\rm Per}(A)={\rm Tr}\left(B\frac{dA}{dt}\right),$$
where $b_{ij}$ is the factor of $a_{ij}$ in ${\rm Per}(A)$. In other words, $b_{ij}$ is the permanent of the $(n-1)\times(n-1)$-matrix obtained from $A$ by deletion of the $i$th row and the $j$th column.